# How to store images from resource drawable into sqlite as a blob?

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I am trying to get the drawable from the resource folder and store it into the `sqlite` database as a blob, but I seem to be getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. I have no idea why as the image is definitely in the resource folder.

This is how I am getting the image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.muffin);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] img = stream.toByteArray();
```

And then in the database, I am storing it as:

```
values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE, product.getImage());
```

and `getImage` returns a byte[]

This is the error I am getting in the logcat:

```
SKImage Decoder:: Factory returned null
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
```

Comment: When the image is available in resource folder why you want to store it in sqlite db ?

Comment: I just wanted to do some testing with blobs as this is my first encounter with it.